# Migration Errors on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a Rails app which I have recently pushed up to Heroku. When I try to migrate the database with:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I am getting the **rake aborted!** message and complains about a table that doesn't exist.

Locally, when I run the migrate command there are no issues so why is Heroku different?

I did experience this issue the last time I migrated on Heroku too - I ended up using:

```
heroku rake db:schema:load
```

to overcome the problem but I really want to get to the root of the problem so it stops happening.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I know which migration file is at fault but is it safe to remove a file from the migrations folder?

Comment: If you are still at the point in your project where you can reset your database, then YES, you can just remove the migration.  If not, you should rollback the migrations to the one prior to the failing one, remove it, and then run the migrations forward again.

Comment: If you're trying to get to the root of the problem, it would help to see the migration file that's at fault; and understand if it has any dependencies on other database objects.  Running `heroku run rake db:migrate` should find the greatest entry in the schema_migrations table and then run any migration with a value greater than that.  Removing the migration won't solve the root problem.